What is this pin for on LTC6253-7
I have tried looking at the datasheet but can't seem to find any information on this pin.


looks like Vee .

I updated my question. at first i thought it was a square root and saw the bottom part was V- but my question is about the top part. What is the S with bar above it? How does I used it and when would i use it?

The circled pin on your circuit diagram doesn't feel like it matches the circle in the package diagram.

Looks like !Shutdown (shutdown not).  Hold it high to make the op amp work

let me update the question. it seems to be confusing everyone.

it is SHDN then

so we all agree it is shutdown not and we hold it to the same voltage as V+?

the datasheet says to let it float

It is a pin to disable the op-amp.
Looking at the datasheet: on page 13 it can be left open or tied high to enable the amplifier.
When pulled low, the output is high impedance allowing simple multiplexing. (page 17 has an example)

